# Stream text response .net 6 ApiController and call from javascript xhr

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to understand how to stream text back to the front end with javascript and .net 6.

On the server I have an ApiController that has a GET request in it like below

```
public async Task<string> GetTsBars(string symbol,string interval,string unit,string barsback,string startdate,string sessiontemplate)
```

I know how to call this normally with ajax but I can't figure out how to convert this into a streaming request that will keep pushing data to the client that I can then read and use on the front end. Any links to examples would be great!

Thank you all in advance,
Tommy

Comment: There is a [link](https://gist.github.com/sohelrana820/63f029d3aa12936afbc50eb785c496c0) about Get Streaming Data Over Jquery Ajax , Hope it can help you.

Comment: I came across this a bit ago and I assumed I was doing it wrong because it never hits the " onprogress " function or any other function even though the backend api is doing it's pulls. My guess is I'm not understanding how to stream from the backend .net 6 API controller